# CMake can't find libraries that are included in the library I'm using

Tags: cmake

When I try to build my project, I get an error:

```
vargmen@vargmen-IdeaPad-L340-15IRH-Gaming:~/codecrafters-bittorrent-cpp$ ./your_bittorrent.sh 
In file included from /home/vargmen/codecrafters-bittorrent-cpp/src/Main.cpp:7:
/home/vargmen/codecrafters-bittorrent-cpp/src/lib/nlohmann/json.hpp:34:10: fatal error: nlohmann/adl_serializer.hpp: No such file or directory
   34 | #include <nlohmann/adl_serializer.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/bittorrent.dir/build.make:63: CMakeFiles/bittorrent.dir/src/Main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/bittorrent.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

It's my `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
   cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
   project(bittorrent-starter-cpp)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20) 
   set(SOURCE_FILES src/Main.cpp src/lib/nlohmann/json.hpp)
   add_executable(bittorrent ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

In my `Main.cpp`, I wrote this to use library: `#include "lib/nlohmann/json.hpp"`
Other header files used in json.hpp are located in the same folder as `json.hpp` itself, but i don't know how to say it to CMake

Answer (score 0):

nlohmann doesn't use relational includes (as, IMO, good libraries should), but demands that the library folders parent is part of the include path.

As such, you need to add your `lib` folder to the include paths of your project.
For this purpose, cmake offers the function [target_include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html).

Add the lib folder (and change your include path to `#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>`) and it should work.

In your particular case, the CMakeLists.txt should therefor contain something akin to:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(bittorrent-starter-cpp)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20) 
set(SOURCE_FILES src/Main.cpp)
add_executable(bittorrent ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_include_directories(bittorrent PRIVATE src/lib/)
```

I have taken the liberty of removing the header file from the sources, as the compiler shall not build it.